# Loading images form file to a Datatable in an optimized way and bind it to a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a database table field with image file names for each row. The relevant images are stored in a particular path.

What I want is to load relevant images to a datatable in an optimized way and bind it to a datagridview.

What I currently do is first load a datatable with file names.
Then, I modify that datatable by adding an image column.
Then, Using a for loop I load images based on the file names.
After that, I bind it to a datagridview and hide the file name field. This works, but I think it's slow.

I suppose this is not the optimized way to do my stuff, because it uses additional for loop to load images one by one. Please let me know how I can do this at once without the loop so that I may reduce the time for a large records.

Thank you

Comment: The DGV has several events related to the row being loaded and formatted.  you should be able to load the image from one of them

Comment: Thanks for your idea, actually I know how to load images to a datagridview. But, I want to do it in an optimized way.

Comment: `how I can do this at once without the loop`...from one of the DGV events (not exactly sure which one would be optimal)... no loop required

Comment: The for loop is not causing you noticeable slowness, it would be the process of dragging the image across the network or just loading it from a local file which gets done whether you do it or dotNet does. What you need to do is do it in the background so it does not slow your UI. There are 3rd party vendors out there that do this type of stuff by default but the default grid control in dotNet does not so you will have to do it yourself. Ideally, you should only load images for VISIBLE rows.

Comment: Thanks Steve,, In my case, is there a way to load images from files to a Datatable only through the DataAdapter so that I can get datatable with images without the use of a loop here. (Actually I need to load relatively large number of records, around 5000 each contains a image, that's why I am finding a better way for this) Thanks,